# Can't located unexpected SyntaxError

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, syntax-error

I am receiving a console error saying this..

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +
```

It is saying for line 929, but when I click on the error, it shows highlighted that the error is coming from the closing line of all of this javascript. What could be the issue in this? There isn't even a + symbol in this line?

Does anyone see what is wrong?

```
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                $('.panel_out input').on('click', function () {
                    var id_to_show = '#' + this.id.replace('_button', '');
                    $(id_to_show).show().siblings().hide();
                });//.first().trigger('click');
            $('#dashboard_welcome').siblings().hide();
            //For the arrow in panel
                $("input.arrowBtn").click(function(){
                    $(this).siblings('.arrow-left').remove();
                    $("<div class='arrow-left'></div>").insertAfter($(this));
                });
                //For tabs to stay active
                 $('.panel_buttons').click(function(){ 
                            $('.panel_buttons').css("background-color","#707070"); 
                            $(this).css("background-color","#000"); })
            });

            //For User Rankings - wins/losses
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#member").on("change", function(){
                $user = this.value;
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "show_user_rankings.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "username="+$user, 
                    success: function(text){ 
                        if(text == "Error!"){ 
                            alert("Unable to get user info!"); 
                        } else { 
                            var txtArr = text.split('|');
                            //0: Contains wins
                            //1: Contains losses
                            $("#wins").val(txtArr[0]);
                            $("#losses").val(txtArr[1]);
                        } 
                    }, 
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                        alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown); 
                    } 
                });
            });
        });

        //For divisions
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
            $("#member_division").on("change", function(){
                $user = this.value;
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "show_division.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: "username="+$user, 
                    success: function(text){ 
                        if(text == "Error!"){ 
                            alert("Unable to get user info!"); 
                        } else { 
                            var txtArr = text.split('|');
                            //0: Contains current division
                            //1: Contains losses
                            $("#current_division").val(txtArr[0]);
                            //$("#losses").val(txtArr[1]);
                        } 
                    }, 
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                        alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown); 
                    } 
                });
            });
        });

         //For Announcements
         $(document).ready(function(){ 
             $("#submit_announcement").on("click", function () {

             var user_message = $("#announcement_message").val();
                //$user = this.value;
                 $user = $("#approved_id").val();
                $.ajax({ 
                    url: "insert_announcements.php", 
                    type: "POST",
                    data: {
                        //   "user_id": $user,
                                        //"message": user_message
                                        "user_message": user_message
                            },
                    success: function (data) {
                           //  console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
                             if (data == "Error!") {
                                 alert("Unable to get user info!");
                                 alert(data);
                             } else {
                                 $(".announcement_success").fadeIn();
                                 $(".announcement_success").show();
                                 $('.announcement_success').html('Announcement Successfully Added!');
                                 $('.announcement_success').delay(5000).fadeOut(400);
                             }
                         },
                         error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                             alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
                             //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
                         }
                     });
                 });
             });
             //Shuffle
            var displayResults = function(data){
                var i = 0;
                var lineheight = 24;
                var time = 3000;
                var interval = setInterval(function(){ 
                    if( i <= data.length){ 
                        console.log( data[i] ); 
                        $('#results').append('<div class="result">' +
                                    //'<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                                    '<div class="shuffle_results">' + data[i].drafted_order + ' '+ data[i].firstname + ' ' + data[i].lastname + '</div>' + 
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="count[]" value="' + data[i].drafted_order + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="firstname[]" value="' + data[i].firstname + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="lastname[]" value="' + data[i].lastname + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="' + data[i].id + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="username[]" value="' + data[i].username + '">' +
                                    '<input type="hidden" name="email[]" value="' + data[i].email + '">' +
                                '</div>');
                       var $this = $('.shuffle_results:last'); 
                        $this.show().animate({ 
                            'left': 0 + 'px', 
                            'bottom': + '0px' 
                            //$(document).height() - (lineheight * data.length)
                        }, { 
                            duration: time 
                        });
                    i++;
                    } else { 
                        clearInterval(interval); 
                    } 
                }, 3000); 
            };
            $(function(){  
                $('form[name="form"]').on('submit', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                   $.post('shuffle_results.php', function(data){ 
                    var o = $.parseJSON(data); 
                    displayResults(o); 
                    });
                    });
                });

            //End Shuffle
            //Owes tables
             $(function() {
                $( "#paid, #partially_paid, #owes" ).sortable({
                  connectWith: ".tdPayment",
                  remove: function(e, ui) {
                    var $this = $(this);
                    var childs = $this.find('div');
                    if (childs.length === 0) {
                       $this.text("Nothing");
                    }
                  },
                  receive: function(e, ui) {
                    $(this).contents().filter(function() {
                        return this.nodeType == 3; //Node.TEXT_NODE
                     }).remove();
                  },
                }).disableSelection();
              });
              //End Owes Table
        </script>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP posted a comment that he found the problem in another part of code not shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here, in your animate code:

```
'bottom': + '0px'
```

Take away the + and it should be OK.

Comment: I just found it. It was in code no where near what is was saying, nor what I posted. Thanks for the look though!

Comment: Also, why have you written it as `'left': 0 + 'px'`? `'left': '0px'` would be fine.

Comment: Not sure. It has been some time ago. It doesn't work like it should anyway.

Comment: That particular `+` is not a syntax error. It doesn't do what the OP wants (it will create a `'bottom'` property with the value `NaN`), so it is wrong, but it is still valid JavaScript that won't give the error mentioned in the question.